# display icon from my sd card

Tags: android, image, resources

I would like my app to grab an image from the phones sd card to use as the notification icon in the status bar, but android needs a resource id to build the notification with an icon.  if I load an image from my sd card, does it have an resource id and how can I get it?  or is there another way to get this to work?

Comment: see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16055073/set-drawable-or-bitmap-as-icon-in-notificatio-in-android) which has a accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if it makes sense to use a notification icon from the sdcard.

- Why would it change during your application?
- If it would not change, place it in the res folder and access it with `R.drawable.name`
- If the user mounts the sdcard, the img will not be available.

I can't think of a way to hack android to place an img from the sdcard. The `Notification` constructor just gets an id as icon.

My recommendation:

Do your notification icon based on your app icon following the [icon Design guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html#statusbarstructure).

Comment: yea, they follow the guide.  the reason why it would change during my application is it updates a status to the user and each user wants a different color scheme.  and each scheme requires about 80 or so image files.  If i were to add each scheme to the app, it would become way to large.  so i wanted the user to select which scheme from the app and have the app download that scheme to the sd card and then apply it.  is there an alternate way to do that?