# Set Drawable or Bitmap as icon In Notification in Android

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I download a image from server as bitmap and convert it to drawable now i want to use this drawable as notification icon. But i am unable to do that. here is my code:

```
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)

    .setContentTitle(title)

    .setContentText(message)

    .setContentIntent(intent)

    .setSmallIcon(bitmap)

    .setWhen(when)

    .build();
```

but icon is a Resources int value so when i used it it gives error.  Any help

Edit:

Now i update my code and now i am doing like that :

```
          Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)

        .setContentTitle(title)

        .setContentText(message)

        .setContentIntent(intent)

        .setSmallIcon(icon)

        .setLargeIcon(bitmap)

        .setWhen(when)

        .build();
```

but it gives large icon on left side and small icon on right side. I don't want this so for this i remove setSmallIcon line and run my code but it not showing me the notifications

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16051724/931982 ... se my answer here

Comment: lol for some reason i dont know why .. the small icon at the right side is called large icon .. only there you can set the bitmap. In higher api you can create your own notification with custom layout

Comment: did you tried with this ? Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.logo,"App ", System.currentTimeMillis());

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you read the developer documents specific to [`Notification.Builder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html) you will see that [`setSmallIcon(int icon)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setSmallIcon) needs a *A resource ID in the application's package of the drawable to use*.

Downloading an image, converting to a bitmap and then setting it to the `setSmallIcon()` is still going to give you an error.

Even if you were to convert the `Bitmap` to a `Drawable` like this for instance:

```
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bmpFinal);
```

it is still going to give you an error because that `Drawable` does **not exist** in your application package.

The only possible solution is to use a `Drawable` resource that exists in your `package` and set it to the `setSmallIcon()` method. Typical usage:

```
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

Alternatively, the [`setLargeIcon (Bitmap icon)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setLargeIcon) requires a Bitmap instance. Without having to make any additional changes in your current code (since you already have a `Bitmap`), you can use that as it is, if it fits your requirement.

If not, you pretty much have to use a `Drawable` resource that is already present in one of the `drawable` folders.

Answer (score 21):

you can try using this method

```
 builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher));
```

http://javatechig.com/android/android-notification-example-using-notificationcompat

Comment: This isn't answering what OP asked.

Answer (score 15):

There is some points about this question, mainly related with API 23+, if you are only interested in setSmallIcon, go to the 2nd and 3rd topics.

1st :

You can set the LargeIcon from a Drawable (instead of Resource id), like the following

```
Drawable drawable= ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.your_drawable);

            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();

            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                            .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
                            .setContentTitle("hahah")
                            .setContentText("Tap to stop")
                            .setOngoing(true);
```

2nd :

If you need to set a small icon in API below 23, you will need to set a resource id like `R.drawable.your_resource`.
The `NotificationCompat.Builder` does not allow you to use Drawables or Bitmaps in `setSmallIcon()`.

3rd :

fortunately , the support has been expanded to `Icon` type on `setSmallIcon()` in version 23+, using the Notification.Builder, like following :

```
 Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.your_drawable);

            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();

            Notification.Builder mBuilder =
                    new Notification.Builder(context)
                            .setSmallIcon(Icon.createWithBitmap(bitmap))
                            .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
                            .setContentTitle("hahah")
                            .setContentText("Tap to stop")
                            .setOngoing(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the last one, even though there's still no solution for old version.. Good to know anyways

Answer (score 6):

Better option get application icon

```
 Drawable drawable=getApplicationInfo().loadIcon(getPackageManager());
 Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();



.setSmallIcon(getApplicationInfo().icon)
.setLargeIcon(bitmap)
```

Comment: Excellent option, but careful this makes the app crashes if the icon is an adaptative icon, as android toolbar doesn't support them.