# How to set bitmap as notification icon in Android

Tags: android

Hello I am looking for the way to set the bitmap which are not in `res` directory. Actually I am getting that icon from the URL and want to set it in the notification area.

Here I am doing but it is only set the icon which are in `res` directory.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_logo)
    .setContentTitle(Util.notificationTitle)
    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
    .bigText(notificationMessage))
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
    .setContentText(notificationMessage);
```

Any idea to set the fetch bitmap from URL and set that icon as `Notification` icon ?

Comment: What if you fetched an downloaded it into your local space and then referenced it that way with its absolute path?  Then it is downloaded and in a sense, cached.

Comment: @Fallenreaper but this method `setSmallIcon` only accept the int in the method argument not any path

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Already answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16055373/1071594

Summary: It's not possible to set a custom small icon, but from API level 11 you can use [setLargeIcon()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setLargeIcon) after you have downloaded your image and converted it to a [Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html).

[edit] There is another [solution](http://www.framentos.com/en/android-tutorial/2012/02/20/how-to-create-a-custom-notification-on-android/):
If you create a completely custom notification with its own view, you could put anything inside that view, including downloaded images.

Answer (score 6):

In API level 23 , Android has introduced new method to setSmallIcon using bitmap downloaded from url.

```
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(Icon.createWithBitmap(yourDownloadedBitmap));
```

Comment: Anyone has a good way to use this in combination with NotificationCompat ( means icon for 23+ and res-id fallback for x<23 ) ?

Comment: This not works, setSmallIcon(int) cannot be applied to android.graphics.drawable.Icon

Comment: Instead of using Icon.createWithBitmap I used IconCompat.createWithBitmap since one of the setSmallIcon method needs an IconCompat object.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can't use directly the URL, but you can use the following statement, but only if you use a large icon.

This statement converts a URL into a BitMap:

```
Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromURL("Your URL");


public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String strURL) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strURL);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now, in your notification builder you can use the following code:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
    .setContentTitle(Util.notificationTitle)
    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
    .bigText(notificationMessage))
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
    .setContentText(notificationMessage);
```

Don't forget the permissions in your Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: See `setSmallIcon` only accept the int from res not any bitmap

Comment: Thanks Williams, I've used it in a large Icon.

Comment: The question was about setSmallIcon and not setLargeIcon

Comment: setting only largeIcon is not enough. smallIcon is mandatory, this code will cause the app to crash

Answer (score -2):

The Simple way to set up a custom png image to Notifications is by create a drawable folder in app/src/main/res folder and paste the image to that folder then you can access that image like this

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.imagename);