# Using new notification of Android v23 in older version

Tags: android, jar, bitmap, notifications

I know there are a lot of questions like mine, but I really need to solve it. As far as I know in [API level 23 , Android has introduced new method to setSmallIcon using bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33967736/925504). So, I can use `Bitmap` to set it in notification. The reason why I can't use `Drawables` as well as `RemoteViews` is no possibilies to have resources in my library(JAR). All icons and bitmaps are stored in `Base64` format(They are small). Is there a quick way to add new `setSmallIcon` implementation to older version of Notification. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a quick way to add new setSmallIcon implementation to older version of Notification.

Not only is there no quick way, there is no way at all.

API 23 introduced a new [`Icon`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Icon.html) class which can be supplied to [`Notification.Builder.setSmallIcon(Icon)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setSmallIcon(android.graphics.drawable.Icon)). This object can be created from

- Bitmap
- URI pointing to an image
- Image file path
- Resource ID pointing to a drawable
- Byte array

This `Icon` class is not present below API 23 and the only way to set a small icon to a notification is to use [`Notification.Builder.setSmallIcon(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setSmallIcon(int)) which takes a drawable resource ID as parameter.

Consider migrating from .jar to .aar.

Comment: Why? Is it have a lot of dependencies?

Comment: is there a way to setSmallicon from byte arrays?

Comment: @EugenPechanec i asked about api 19.

Comment: @SHM And how am I supposed to know if you don't write it? Besides, did you read the answer? It already explains it's not possible, sorry.

Comment: @EugenPechanec you should know that, because i commented below your answer which already states "api 23".

Comment: @SHM The last paragraph: "This **Icon class is not present ***below*** API 23** and the **only way to set a small icon to a notification is to use** Notification.Builder.setSmallIcon(int) which takes **a drawable resource ID** as parameter." How is that not clear?