# Push Notification image from url?

Tags: android, push-notification

Android push notification image is by default applications image. Is it possible that the icon of my push notification can be load through an external image url ? Is this possible ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24840282/load-image-from-url-in-notification-android

Comment: refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23837198/1157879)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load image from url in notification Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24840282/load-image-from-url-in-notification-android)

Comment: Answers in the comment section worth exploring :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to download the image convert into bitmap and then create notification.