# Xamarin Android C# - Efficient Bitmap to Icon Converter below API 23

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, icons

Is there a support library for `Icon.CreateWithBitmap(bm)` where you can use it below API 23?
Or something that can is compatible , to set a small icon in a notification builder

Comment: `SetSmallIcon(Resource.mipmap.ic_launcher)` method will set a small icon for your notification, what do you want?

Comment: This is not what i want - im generating a bitmap using a canvas and paint, and i need it converted from a bitmap to an icon so i can set it

Comment: [You want convert bitmap to drawable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415619/how-to-convert-a-bitmap-to-drawable-in-android)  Could you please show your code?

Comment: Is a drawable able to be set as icon for notifications?

Comment: `using (Icon ico = Icon.CreateWithBitmap(bm))
                        {
                            builder.SetSmallIcon(ico);
                        }`
This is literally the code, **bm** being a bitmap that has been generated, and i need a way for it to get converted to an icon so i can set the small icon of the notification

Comment: After reading [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/Notification.java), I can't find a way to custom the small icon, and [there is a answer you should take a look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836920/how-to-set-bitmap-as-notification-icon-in-android)

Comment: Yes ive seen that, but I cant figure how to set the drawable bitmap converted to exist in my package resource after being generated

Comment: You can't convert, if you can convert it, then it will be hack, you can also change others app's resource. You can think it.