# Set a bitmap to Android Notification setSmallIcon

Tags: java, android, bitmap, notifications

Hi i have a generated merged bitmap and need to set it in Android Notification SmallIcon, how i can do this?

If i try use bitmap like drawable icon i get error.

```
Bitmap bitmap = dynamicIcon.merge();
builder.setSmallIcon(bitmap);
```

Thanks.

Comment: builder.setSmallIcon(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap));

Comment: @Lingeshwaran seeing builder.setSmallIcon(Icon int) , how can we pass BitmapDrawable? Can u pls explain ... ?

Comment: @Rupali check this link it might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16055073/set-drawable-or-bitmap-as-icon-in-notification-in-android

Answer (score 1):

You have to use icon from res/drawable folder for setSmallIcon().

But in API23, you can use bitmap

```
    setSmallIcon(Icon.createWithBitmap(bitmap))
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting bitmap as small icon is available from android M and cannot be used in lower versions.

first you have to check if version is above M or not.

if it's bellow you should use `NotificationCompat.Buidler`

if it's above android M you should use `Notification.Builder`

in `Notification.Buidler` you have a method called `setSmallIcon(Icon)` that can be uses like this.

```
builder.setSmallIcon(Icon.createFromBitmap(bitmap));
```

so if you really need this feature& you only can use it in api level 26 and above.