# Xamarin Android - Custom Notification Tray Icon(status bar)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, notifications, icons

Ive made a custom notification using RemoteView - does anyone know how to set the icon in **that** using a bitmap? or a drawable thats not in a package - or at least show how to add a package/resource or update it so it can be set.

Im targeting minimum API of 17 , so `Icon.CreateWithBitmap` is sadly not an option for me since the min API there is 23.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`SetLargeIcon()`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.Notification+Builder.SetLargeIcon/) to change the icon to your bitmap.
The `SetLargeIcon()` requires a Bitmap instance.

For example:

`builder.SetLargeIcon(bitmap);`

The official document: [notifications](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/local_notifications_in_android/#large-icon-format)

The [`SetSmallIcon()`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.Notification+Builder.SetSmallIcon/p/System.Int32/) needs a A resource ID in the application's package of the drawable to use. You could just copy your icons and paste them into `drawable` folder. And set the Build Action to AndroidResource in Properties

For example:

```
builder.SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.YOUR_ICON);
```

If you want to set bitmap as ImageView background, please try [`SetImageBitmap()`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Widget.ImageView.SetImageBitmap/p/Android.Graphics.Bitmap/):

```
imageview.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Or

```
 imageview.SetImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Drawable.YOUR_ICON ));
```

You could also refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16055073/set-drawable-or-bitmap-as-icon-in-notification-in-android/16055373#16055373).

Comment: That is useless for me- i need it to show a string thats been generated in the status bar(top of the device)